# Why cannot run Java web app on Tomcat 8 if on maven pluggin Tomcat 7 it is working?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have got a simple project based on Maven. I am using plugin for tomcat 7 in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <path>/</path>
      <port>9090</port>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run my project through Intellij using this Tomcat 7 plugin everything work. The problem is when I configured into Intellij e.g. Tomcat 8 and when I run it I have got communicat like below:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message Not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

What can be the reason that on plugin Tomcat 7 everything work, but does not work on Tomcat 8 (no plugin, just simple configuration)?

[image]

My web.xml file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAddAdvertisement</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.tom.servlets.ServletAddAdvertisement</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAddAdvertisement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletAddAdvertisement</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I think that during the deployment Tomcat does not see the war file. There should be some way to specify/configure it by deployment descriptor. When I deploy my myPorject.war file manually on Tomcat 8 everything work.

Thank you.

Comment: When configuring the server in Intellij there is option an Edit Configuration -> Tomcat Server -> Deployment -> there you need to choose appreciate Artifact.

Comment: I guess your comment is the solution for your own question. In this case, please add it as an answer so the question does not stay unanswered. And good to see that you solved it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the server in Intellij there is an option Edit Configuration -> Tomcat Server -> Deployment -> there you need to choose appreciate Artifact.